# Objective-C: Trying to use Apple's MultipleDetailView

Tags: objective-c

I am working on trying to make a splitview based application.  I am trying to use Apple's MultipleDetailView example code

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html

I have never really used example code like this (I usually just atart from scratch).  All i did was copy the code into the correct classes of my app, but when I try to run it on the simulator the app doesn't open.

I feel like I am maybe forgetting something obvious, since I didn't code it myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Any error messages when you **run** it?

Comment: it says that the AppDelegate class and the DetailViewController class are unkown in the Interface Builder file.  I am guessing then that I need to do soemthing on the interface builder side of things?

Comment: You copied the code, but did you copy the XIB and hook everything up?

Comment: I didnt see a xib to copy?  I will look into it now though thanks

Comment: although I did hook up the secondview which i created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual debugging technique applies. Put a breakpoint somewhere early in the program -- the first line of `main()` for instance, and debug from there. Do you hit the breakpoint? If yes, move forward through the code until you find the line that causes the problem. If no, try to back up even further if you can, and also look for any clues as to what's going wrong. If the app is running at all, there should be some sort of error message in the console output.

"...the app doesn't open" doesn't tell us nearly enough to help you. Something like "the app delegate is instantiated, but it's `window` and `splitViewController` properties are nil" goes much further toward getting to the root of the problem.

Comment: I understand how to debug (I usually use NSLog to see if i get to certain points), I just assumed that the code on Apple's site would be complete... I am fairly new at objective-c and am just looking for a starting point for my app

Comment: @user1486911 The sample code *is* complete. You can open the project file and run the example in the simulator with no changes. I did exactly that and it ran fine, so it seems that whatever problem you're having was introduced when you moved the code into your app. The way to figure out what's wrong is to debug, right?

Comment: Thanks for testing it out.  The error I keep running into: "Unkown class <myclass> in interface builder file.  And the 2 classes its complaining about are the app delegate and the detailviewcontroller